# notification bar - clock width?

Tags: android

How to get the clock on notification bar size in pixel?
Do anyone know?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At best, that information will only be available inside of the firmware somewhere, inaccessible by SDK applications. SDK applications should neither know nor care whether the notification bar has a clock, let alone its size and position.